# Problems with authorization on Sonarcloud

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

Good afternoon. I created an account on sonarcloud via github, but after I changed my username to github, I can not log in to sonarcloud. A message is displayed:

"You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator.

Reason: You can't sign up because email '*****' is already used by an existing user. This means that you probably already registered with another account."

Comment: You should send this request to https://about.sonarcloud.io/contact/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Fabrice, for the moment the only way to fix this issue is to send a message on about.sonarcloud.io/contact to fix this issue.

This issue should be fixed in a cleaner way by https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1161.